# Error connecting to db mssql php zend 1.12

Tags: php, sql-server, zend-framework, pdo, database-connection

I have a problem connecting to a db with zend framework 1.12 and zend studio. The code in the application.ini to connect to the db is the following:

```
 resources.db.adapter = pdo_mssql

 resources.db.params.host = "IPADDRESS\SQLEXPRESS"
 resources.db.params.username = sa
 resources.db.params.password = XXXXXXXX
 resources.db.params.dbname = namedb
 resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true
 resources.db.params.pdoType = dblib
 resources.db.params.charset= "utf-8"
```

The db is available online (I checked) but i get the following error:

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[01002] Adaptive Server connection failed (severity 9)
```

I know this error is a connection error (the pdo doesn't find the db) and i've found a [tutorial](http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/Connecting-to-MS-SQL-Server-td671976.html) in a forum which should help (it uses zend framework with the same libraries and type of db i use, on a mac). But i think the pdo type is configured somewhere elsein my machine as i don't find in my Abstract.php:

```
 protected $_pdoType = 'dblib';
```

The pdo type is set in the application.ini, the code i pasted before. The log says the error is in those lines:

```
 in /usr/local/zend/var/libraries/Zend_Framework_1/1.12.3/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:129 

            $this->_connection = new PDO(
            $dsn,
            $this->_config['username'],
            $this->_config['password'],
            $this->_config['driver_options']
        );
```

But i cannot understand what I'm missing.. Any hint?

Answer (score 1):

This article by rob allen will be usefull i think , [Zf Coonect To MSSQL](http://akrabat.com/winphp-challenge/zend-framework-connection-to-sql-server-using-sqlsrv/)

as described there in detail you can use following,

```
resources.db.adapter = "sqlsrv"
resources.db.host = "host"
resources.db.dbname = "DatabaseName"
resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true 
resources.db.driver_options.ReturnDatesAsStrings = true
```

Hope That Helps

also relevant DOC from zend framwork official document [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.adapter.html#zend.db.adapter.adapter-notes.sqlsrv).

Comment: It complains about a missing extension, i should load sqlsrv to make it work i assume. How to do it?

Comment: you can use this http://docs.gurock.com/testrail-admin/howto-installing-sqlsrv i think..

Comment: i'm on a mac, i caanot use sqlsrv as an extesion, it doen't exist for mac. However thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

Microsoft SQL Server database connection info

```
db.mssqlServer.adapter          = PDO_MSSQL
db.mssqlServer.config.pdoType   = dblib
db.mssqlServer.config.host      = server_ip_or_url
db.mssqlServer.config.dbname    = database_name
db.mssqlServer.config.username  = "mssql_user"
db.mssqlServer.config.password  = "mssql_password"
db.mssqlServer.config.driver_options.PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
```